# ¿como puedo agregarle un background-color al menu al hacer click en el icono?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Tengo esto

```js
/*========== ADD NAV BACKGROUND ON CLICK ==========*/

$(document).ready(function () { //when document loads completely.
  $('#hamburguer').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('solid');
  });
});
```

```css
/*============ NAVIGATION ============*/
.navbar {
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 2rem;
}

.svg-inline--fa.fa-w-14{
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

button:focus {
outline: 1px dotted;
outline: 5px auto -webkit-focusring-color;
}

.navbar-nav li {
  padding-right: 0.8rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #FFF;
  padding-top: 0.8rem;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link.active,.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
  color: #1EBBA3;
}

.navbar.solid {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)!important;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/nuno.png"></a>
        <button id="hamburguer" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
          <span class="custom-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#home" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#features" class="nav-link">FEATURES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">PORTFOLIO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">PRICING</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#team" class="nav-link">TEAM</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#skills" class="nav-link">SKILLS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#clients" class="nav-link">CLIENTS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

---

Es asi ya lo resolvi, mil gracias por tomarse el tiempo.

```js
/*========== ADD NAV BACKGROUND ON CLICK ==========*/

$(document).ready(function () { //when document loads completely.
  $('#hamburguer').click(function() {
    $('.navbar').addClass('solid');
  });
});
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: no se agrega el background al hacer click :(

Comment: Podrias primero agregar el CSS necesario para que tu menu se vea igual que en tu pagina? Tienes algun error en consola?

Comment: ok si, ya lo edite :)

Comment: Agregalo en el mismo fragmento, no en uno aparte, asi podemos correr el codigo y replicar el menu

Comment: ah si perdon, ya esta

Comment: Tambien tienes que agregar la libreria de jQuery; edita el fragmento de nuevo; al lado izquierdo tienes unas opciones para frameworks, selecciona la primera opcion que aparece en "jQuery"

Comment: me dice que mi reputacion no es suficiente para el chat, perdon

Comment: Que chat? Me refiero a que cuando estas en la ventana de edicion del fragmento hay una opcion para añadir librerias :)

Comment: estoy usando bootstrap4

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias aplicarlo asi:

**Actualizado a Bootstrap4**

```js
$(document).ready(function () { //when document loads completely.
  $('#btnCollapse').click(function() {
    $('#navbarTogglerDemo03').css('background-color','yellow');
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>




<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" id="btnCollapse">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas he colocado '**ID**' al **button** que es el que ejecuta el evento de mostrar la lista de tu menu y aplico el estilo con jquery..!!

Comment: OP no ha aclaro siquiera cual version de Bootstrap esta usando; la cual a juzgar por su codigo, es Bootstrap 4, no la 3 que usas; creo que es buena la ayuda con la respuesta pero tambien creo que es mejor que primero logre formular la pregunta adecuadamente y con la informacion necesaria

Comment: si es bootstrap4

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo tu ejemplo sería algo así:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#hamburguer').click(function() {
    $(.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.fixed-top).addClass('solid');
  });
});

.solid {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)!important;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
```

Solo debes cambiar el selector que usaste `$(this)` por uno que realmente seleccione tu menú, como por ejemplo: `$(.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.fixed-top)`